# when we should use tf.function decorator

Tags: tensorflow, keras, decorator, python-decorators, eager-execution

I'm trying to boost the performance of a simple 2NN. Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf

# load Mnist 
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(path='mnist.npz')
X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

# configure the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr=0.1), metrics=['accuracy'])
# train and evaluate the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
```

Now, I wounder either there is a case to use `@tf.function` decorator or not, and if it's needed, how?

Answer (score 0):

Your code only used builtin functions and classes so there is no need to use a `@tf.function` decorator. `@tf.function` is basically used to convert a normal function into a TensorFlow Graph as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function). Since you are only using the builtin modules and functions, they are already treated as a graph by the TF compiler.