# Under what condition can we use @tf.function?

Tags: function, tensorflow

I have heard that `tf.function` can build graph and accelerate computation. But when can we use it?

From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306632/when-we-should-use-tf-function-decorator), seems like:

> when we are not using built-in functions

Any more specific answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#:%7E:text=To%20be%20more%20specific%20about%20the%20terminology%3A%201,function%2C%20returning%20a%20Function%20object.%20More%20items...%20) that count pros of tf.function.
Imagine you have a loss function, adding this keyword on top of your function can helps Tensorflow to run it faster however you might face error like

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

if you are not initializing all variables in the first run.